# Sending POST data to php using angular 5

Tags: php, angular, rest, web-services, angular5

I'm trying to call a web service from angular 5 to PHP.

I'm using POST method but I have trouble retrieving data in PHP side.

Send data is shown in payload but it's not retrieved in php side.

**Angular service.ts**

```
this.URL = "http://localhost/angular/WEBSERVICE_PHP/test.php";

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let data = 'visitor_id=55';

return this.http
.post(this.URL,JSON.stringify(data),{
    headers: headers
})
.map( Response => console.log(Response) );
```

**PHP PAGE**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET");
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"'); // Makes IE to support cookies
header('content-type: text/plain');  
header("content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X- 
Requested-With");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 172800");

if(isset($_POST))
{
    // $post = 'test data';     // This data get sent
    //   return $post;
    echo $post = $_POST['visitor_id'];
    return $post; 
}
```

Comment: Don't use post, try `file_get_contents('php://input')` since you are sending JSON

Comment: Why are you applying `JSON.stringify` on `data`? The way `data` is defined it looks like it should be `JSON.parse` instead.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` It does not contain what you think it does. Try `let data = {visitor_id: 55};` and `.post(this.URL,data,{`, and remove the json header instead. It should be able to read the data without having to use json. If you do want to use json, don't forget to decode it in PHP before you try to access anything.

Comment: @delboy1978uk -  That worked, but how to retrieve each values if I am sending multiple values

Comment: you'll now have a string, right? `json_decode($string, true);` Let me know if it works and I'll put a proper answer up for everyone

Comment: @delboy1978uk - It worked with  file_get_contents('php://input') . But how to access the data as POST.

Comment: Send the data as post, not a json string!

Comment: @delboy1978uk - No, that does'nt work. I removed json stringify and tried to use POST['visitor_id'] on PHP. It doesn't work

Comment: what's wrong with just doing it the way that worked? this is how you work with json

Comment: @delboy1978uk - Your method works all fine. But the server side uses S_POST method for all operations. To avoid rewriting whole post requests.

Comment: you could say `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` ?

Comment: @delboy1978uk - Even though crooked that works  Thanks. Please post the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When "posting" JSON, you won't see `$_POST`.

Instead do this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

If it MUST be `$_POST`, you can assign the `$array` to `$_POST`.

The other solution is from the Angular side, instead of sending the JSON string, send a proper post! (I'm not an Angular man, maybe someone can comment and I'll add the code!)